# Envio de e-mail PHP7 Ubuntu com erro

Tags: email, php

Não estou conseguindo enviar e-mail pela minha conta cloud da Vultr. Tenho a conta desbloqueada para enviar emails mas nada acontece quando eu envio. Tenho instalado o sendmail e quando envio um email por ssh ou php ele "envia" sem erros.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(!empty($_POST['contactname']) && !empty($_POST['contactemail']) && !empty($_POST['contactmessage'])) {
    $to = 'info@MEUDOMINIO.COM'; // Your e-mail address here.
    $body = "\nName: {$_POST['contactname']}\nEmail: {$_POST['contactemail']}\n\n\n{$_POST['contactmessage']}\n\n";
    mail($to, "Mensagem via Website", $body, "From: {$_POST['contactemail']}"); // E-Mail subject here.
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: A função `mail` não utiliza `exceptions`. Verifique se não está na caixa de spam e verifique se o `header` está correto.

Comment: Nesse caso me parece que devido ao servidor de email não ter autenticação muito menos configurações para ser um servidor de email. Você deve ter um servidor de email com reverso configurado e autenticação, depois disso recomendo usar o projeto PHPMailer para enviar seus emails.